# How to use numpy array inputs in tensorflow RNN

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, batch-processing, sklearn-pandas

I just curious on how how to generate a sequence, batches and or epochs to feed into a tensor flow model, a multi_layer RNN graph from a numpy array. Originally numpy array was generated from pandas dataset and a Sklearn split below.

From Numpy to Pandas

```
#define features and labels using X, Y from a numpy array
 X = Input_Output_Matrix.iloc[:, 0:3].values
 y = np.around(Input_Output_Matrix.iloc[:, 3], decimals=1).values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
  from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, 
        random_state = 0)
```

Note: Very important

```
y_train.shape
```

Out[37]:
(6721, 100)

```
X_train.shape
```

Out[38]:
(6721, 3)

Now the shape of

## Scaling the features to speed up the model

```
 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
 sc = StandardScaler()
 X = sc.fit_transform(X)


res = tf.one_hot(indices=y, depth=100)
with tf.Session() as sess:
     y = sess.run(res)
```

In order to generate the configuration parameters.

```
# Configuration is wrapped in one object for easy tracking and passing.
  class RNNConfig():
       input_size = X_train.shape[1]
       output_size = y_train.shape[1]
       num_steps = 100
       lstm_size = y_train.shape[0]//100
       num_layers = 4
       keep_prob = 0.8
       batch_size = 100
       init_learning_rate = 0.001
       learning_rate_decay = 0.99
       init_epoch = 5
       max_epoch = 5000

DEFAULT_CONFIG = RNNConfig()
```

The input parameters used for the config are actually based on the shape of the numpy array, lets say input_size = 3 for 3 inputs and output_size = 100 derived from the out puts from the one hot encoding i.e depth equals 100.

```
 #one hot encoding to generate 10 columns for the labels

 res = tf.one_hot(indices=y, depth=100)

with tf.Session() as sess:
y = sess.run(res)

with multi_lstm_graph.as_default():

    x_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, DEFAULT_CONFIG.num_steps, 
                          DEFAULT_CONFIG.input_size])

    y_label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, DEFAULT_CONFIG.num_steps, 
                          DEFAULT_CONFIG.output_size])

    learning_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, None)

    def _create_one_cell():
        lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(config.lstm_size, 
                                           state_is_tuple=True)

        if config.keep_prob < 1.0:
            lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell, 
                              output_keep_prob=config.keep_prob)
        return lstm_cell               
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([_create_one_cell() for _ in 
               range(config.num_layers)], state_is_tuple=True) if 
                      config.num_layers > 1 else _create_one_cell()

    val, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x_data, dtype=tf.float32)

    val = tf.transpose(val, [1, 0, 2])

        last = tf.gather(val, int(val.get_shape()[0]) - 1)

        weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([config.lstm_size, 
                  config.input_size]))

        bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.01, shape=[config.input_size]))

        y_pred = tf.matmul(last, weight) + bias
```

For the graph features

The tensor flow features are as listed below,
        # Now for the training session

```
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
                 (logits=y_pred, labels=y_label), name="graph_loss")
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
        minimize = optimizer.minimize(loss )
        tf.summary.scalar("loss_mse", loss)
```

Lastly for the training session

```
with tf.Session(graph=Multilayer_RNN_Graph_Cell) as sess:    

    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
```

Configuration parameters

```
    learning_rates_to_use = [config.init_learning_rate*
                           (config.learning_rate_decay ** max(
                    float(i + 1 -config.init_epoch), 0.0)) for i in 
                                         range(config.max_epoch)]

    test_data_feed = {inputs: X_test, targets: X_test, learning_rate: 0.0}
```

Here is how I try to Iterating over the Epochs.

```
        for epoch_step in range(DEFAULT_CONFIG.max_epoch):
        current_lr = learning_rates_to_use[epoch_step]
```

Here are my batches again based on the shape of the input array, specifically the number of features.

```
        for _ in range(int(X_train.shape[0]/config.batch_size)):
            rand_index = np.random.choice(len(X_train), 
                                 size=config.batch_size)
            batch_X = X_train[rand_index].reshape((1, config.num_steps, 
                                 config.input_size))
            #indexing of 1_D np.array
            batch_y = y_train[rand_index].reshape((1, config.num_steps, 
                             config.output_size)) 

            '''Each loop below completes one epoch training.'''
            train_data_feed = {inputs: batch_X,
                                targets: batch_y,
                                learning_rate: 0}    

            '''Each loop below completes one epoch training.'''              
            train_loss, _ = sess.run([loss, minimize], train_data_feed)
            cost_history = np.append(cost_history, train_loss)                

            '''results of the Session'''

            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', hm_epochs,'loss:', 
                        cost_history)  

            '''In order to test for Model Accuracy '''

        if epoch_step%10 == 0:                
            test_loss, _pred, _summary = sess.run([loss, prediction, 
                             merged_summary], test_data_feed)
            assert len(_pred) == len(y_test)
            print ("Epoch %d [%f]:" % (epoch_step, current_lr), test_loss)
```

Now for my out put. I get the below error. I have particular issue with the logits_size=[1,3] which I don't know how it was generated. It does not relater to either of the matrices( Input matrix, X_train or output, matrix, y_train.). My question is this how do I match the logits_size to the labels_size=[100,100].

Thanks in advance

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\MAULIDI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1326     try:
-> 1327       return fn(*args)
   1328     except errors.OpError as e:

C:\Users\MAULIDI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1305                                    feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1306                                    status, run_metadata)
   1307 

C:\Users\MAULIDI\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     87             try:
---> 88                 next(self.gen)
     89             except StopIteration:

C:\Users\MAULIDI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    467   finally:

InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[1,3] labels_size=[100,100]
     [[Node: train/SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](train/Reshape, train/Reshape_1)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here in this part of your code.

```
 val = tf.transpose(val, [1, 0, 2])

 last = tf.gather(val, int(val.get_shape()[0]) - 1)
```

The output of the RNN is (timestep, batch_index, data) and you are transposing to (batch_index, timestep, data). Then you do gather with indices = shape[0] - 1  on axis 0 (that's the default). So you are taking the last element of batch. You probably want to specify to axis 1.

Another way to do it, that would keep the code cleaner is:

```
last = val[:, -1, :]
```

I'm guessing you are only doing one time step in your test so that should explain the 1.
I don't see any other bug right now so I would guess your input_size is 3 and when you do the matrix multiplication you get the [1, 3].

Check that the weight has a shape like (x, 100). If your batch size is 100 fixing those two should give a result that has the right shape.

Comment: InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[1,100] labels_size=[100,100]
  [[Node: train/SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](train/Reshape, train/Reshape_1)]]                         .....after changing it to int(val[:, -1, :].get_shape()[1]) -1, almost getting there, now if I can only figure out the difference in shapes.

Comment: @MAULIDIBARASA You shouldn't need to get the same anymore. `last = val[:, -1, :]`  will make `last` contain the values of the last time_step for every example in the batch (what I think you wanted). This replaces the `tf.gather` completely.

Comment: For my code to work. These other necessary re-adjustments were necessary; weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([config.lstm_size, 
                  config.output_size])) & bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.01, shape=[config.output_size]))

Comment: And further change of  test_data_feed = {inputs: X_test, targets: X_test, learning_rate: 0.0}, to test_data_feed = {inputs: X_test, targets: y_test, learning_rate: 0.0}